# description or popup showing cfgrid column header full text

Tags: html, css, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

i want to know if  there is any possibility to show the full text from a cfgridcolumn header like the attribute `"ALT"` in html or using a popup just for the header or a hover method.

Comment: I suspect not but I'm willing to be embarassed.

Comment: Without the means to do this using ColdFusion, the simplest approach would be to manipulate the DOM using javascript after the page is rendered and you can easily add the `alt` or `title` attribute that way.

Comment: hi sir , thanks  it's a very good idea but the problem that i can 't put an "id" in cfgridcolumn it does not accept that attribute .

Comment: I suggest writing a simple page that outputs a few rows of data using a `cfgrid`.  Then view the resulting html source code and see if there is anything potentially useful.